# Uploading CSV file and converting it into custom serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Guys, I'm struck with importing CSV file using Django rest framework 2.o

Here is the exact requirement.

```
 @transaction.atomic
    @list_route(methods=['POST'])
    def upload(self, request):
        print(request.data)  #getting this "<QueryDict: {'data-file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 69106231_1518183310391.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>"
        CSVParser.parse(parser_context=request.data)
      return xxx
```

When I'm uploading the file I'm getting "object" which I showed in code. I want to send that "request.data" as param and parse that into text and serialize it. Serializing can be done by myself. Can someone please provide me with some suggestion on which module is best to use and how to use that request.data to parse.

Thank You..!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [django-rest-framework-csv](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv)

apply CSVRenderer class on your api view.